# Android SQLiteStatement and UPDATE SET... WHERE IN (1,2,3)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I wanted to execute the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE X SET y=10 WHERE z IN (1,2,3,4);
```

As the set can contain any number of elements, I created the following SQL string statement:

```
UPDATE X SET y=? WHERE z IN (?);
```

Next I nicely precompiled it and used `SQLiteStatement` class for bidning parameters in the following way:

```
statement.bindLong(1, myLong);
statement.bindString(2, "1,2,3,4");
statement.executeUpdateDelete();
```

I hoped naively it will work. No way. If there is only one value as second parameter,ex.

```
 statement.bindString(2, "1");
```

it works then. Otherwise no chance.

Isn't it some kind of bug? Any other proposal how to do in in elegant way? Sure I can put directly the values into String statement:

```
UPDATE X SET y=? WHERE z IN (?);
```

but then precompilation is not possible. :(

Comment: Yes, a statement with input parameter using `?` doesn't work very well with `IN` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind many longs in one call.

What you should do is using a SQL string statement like :

```
UPDATE X SET y=? WHERE z IN (?,?,?,?);
```

Comment: But I don't know in advance how many elements I will have in that set. So no way.

Comment: Where does your elements come from ?

Comment: User choice (how many elements user select in the screen, so for each element I have database id and next I executed update operation in database).

Comment: OK, so use a for loop to construct your query string with ?, then you will be able to call as many statement.bindLong as you need. But no way to bind an array of long in SQLiteStatement.

Comment: But then there is huge difference in efficiency.... loop of statements against one statement with a set of data. Thanks a lot for all help but it's hard to believe Android libraries doesn't support that.